# Divide flask routes into multiple modules without using blueprints?

Tags: flask

I'd like to divide routes into multiple modules, but I don't want to use blueprints as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994325/how-to-divide-flask-app-into-multiple-py-files). The [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) imply I can just import my views files in `__init__.py`, but I can’t seem to get more than one to work. Should more than one be able to work?

This is a pared-down version of my `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

#
# App Configuration
#

gApp = Flask(__name__)

gApp.config.from_object(__name__)

gApp.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True,
    ...
))

#
#   Import the views. I don't know why I can't do more than one
#

import tsint.app
import tsint.admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this is perfectly acceptable. As I was trying to re-create the error I got to round out the question, I got it to work. I decided to leave this here to help someone else.

I must’ve gotten an import statement wrong somewhere (Flask is very bad about telling you which import actually fails).

Comment: Do you have any more insight on this?  What did the failure look like, etc?

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm sorry, that was so long ago I don't remember any more.