# seperate python flask files into multiple files

Tags: python, reactjs, mongodb, flask

I've already read much about it on stack overflow but now I'm struggling with an issue and don't know how to fix it.

My `main.py` looks like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)


# connect to LiTags database
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/LiTags"

mongo = PyMongo(app)

CORS(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

then I seperated some database requests (MongoDB) in another file(`requests.py`). I know that it's not necessary right now because there are not that much requests right now but there will be more after I fixed this problem.

So this is my `requests.py`:

```
from main import app, mongo
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Blueprint
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def getProjects():
    result = []
    projects = mongo.db.literature

    for field in projects.find():
        result.append(
            {"_id": str(field["_id"]), "project_name": field["project_name"]})

    return jsonify(result)
```

this is generally my frontend (ReactJS) request to flask:

```
// get project names from the backend
  getProjects() {
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ projects: res.data });
      })
  }
```

before I seperated the requests in `requests.py` from the `main.py` my program worked but now I get an error in the inspect tool in the browser which says:

```
"GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 404 (NOT FOUND)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:63)"
```

Comment: BTW: most people and tutorials/documentations use name `views.py` instead of `requests.py` for file with code which use `@app.route`.

Comment: please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994325/how-to-divide-flask-app-into-multiple-py-files

Comment: you have to `import requests` in `main.py` - without import it never use code from  `requests.py` so it doesn't use code `@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])` and when browser try to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` then Flask doesn't know what to do.

Comment: BTW: you will have problem with `circular import` because in `main.py` you have to import `requests.py` but `requests.py` already imports `main.py`. You would have to create new file ie. `run.py` which imports first from `main.py`, next from `requests.py` and finally it runs `app.run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main.py` you would have to import `requests.py`

```
from requests import *
```

because `main.py` doesn't know that you have code in other file .

But there can be problem with `circular imports` - `main.py` has to import `requests.py` but `requests.py` aready imports `main.py` and it makes problem.

You may have to split main in two files:

**main.py** - which doesn't need code from `reuqests` so it doesn't have to import it

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

# connect to LiTags database
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/LiTags"

mongo = PyMongo(app)

CORS(app)
```

**run.py** - which needs code from `requests` (but `requests` doesn't import it)

```
from main import *
#from main import app
from requests import *

#from models import *
#from views import *
#from admin import *    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and now you would have to use `run.py` instead of `main.py` to start server.

```
python run.py
```

---

**BTW:** most people and tutorials/documentations use name `views.py` instead of `requests.py` for file with code which use `@app.route`. Eventaully I would use name `api.py` because these views return JSON data like in many APIs.