# How to let Python execute script in each folder

Tags: python, file, flask, structure

I struggled with this question for 2 days and has no idea.
I have 3 folders containing 3 individual python scripts each folder script run a function.

My question is how can I access them individually?

for only 1 folder, I create, say app.py with all routes inside.  but how can I access 3 folder individually and can run individual function?

My file skeleton likes:

app.py (entrance)
|---departmentA
......|-------runme.py
......|-------templates
...........|-----index.html
|---departmentB
......|-------runme.py
......|-------templates
...........|-----index.html
|---departmentC
......|-------runme.py
......|-------templates
...........|-----index.html

Thanks
Alex

Comment: sorry forget to tell...i am running Flask  how to use the route to access 3 different folders?

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/ and  [what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application) and  [how-to-divide-flask-app-into-multiple-py-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994325/how-to-divide-flask-app-into-multiple-py-files) .. plenty of ressources already on SO

Comment: [edit] your question with a [mre].

Comment: You can do this using Blueprints.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

File Structure:

```
app.py
/departmentA
    __init__.py
    routes.py
    runme.py
    /pages/departmentA
        index.html
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import departmentA

skill_app = Flask(__name__)
skill_app.register_blueprint(departmentA.bp)

print(departmentA.my_func())

skill_app.run()
```

/departmentA/**init**.py

```
from .routes import bp
from .runme import my_func
```

/departmentA/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from .runme import my_func

bp = Blueprint('dept_A', __name__, template_folder='pages', url_prefix='/department_A')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    print(my_func())
    return render_template('departmentA/index.html')
```

/departmentA/runme.py

```
def my_func():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Use same format in other departments.

Comment: Hi Thanks I am new to Blueprint.   so I copied the same structure and I can type  http://127.0.0.1/departmentA/  it will route to departmentA/ and http://127.0.0.1/departmentB/  it will route to departmentB/  right?  also the python code will also be run within each department?  sorry I am new to Blueprint...need to digest

Comment: Ok I copied and it works to open different HTML.  However, inside each html, say HTMLA I need to call  for example <form method="post" action="/upload2" enctype="multipart/form-data">  so "/upload" will trigger the route in app.py   and in HTMLB, will call action "/sendemail"  also will trigger the route in app.py......my question is if I have many pages, then app.py will have many routes to handle different HTML's post requests?

Comment: oh i misunderstood and after testing it a bit clear now...everything is route to "routes.py" in each department.