# Why @app.route('/login') doesn't work while it defined in another module

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask. I was wondering if I can separate code to a different module in Flask (I know Blueprint can do that). So I tried to separate code like this:

```
Flask-Project
  -- app.py  
  -- login.py
```

and here is `app.py` code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and in `login.py`:

```py
from app import app


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return 'login'
```

when I run this Flask project,I try http://127.0.0.0:5000/login, it shows:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. 
If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Why does http://127.0.0.0:5000/login not work?

Comment: How are you running your app? It seems the code in login.py is never run, which is expected if you are just doing `python app.py` or similar, since nowhere in app.py is the code in login.py referenced.

Comment: I run the code in Pycharm， it run well while there only  app.py ，but when i divide the code to a new login.py file，http://127.0.0.1:5000/login can't be reached. I don't konw how this happen. I use ```from app import app``` to make sure app.route can be invoked. I still don‘t understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: As I said, _the code in login.py is not run_. Yes you defined the route there, but nothing in app.py is loading/calling the code in login.py. Either use blueprints or see the answer in the link I shared: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59155127/2745495

Comment: thanks for ur patient Gino,I think I need to learn more about how Flask works

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `login.py` module so that the handler is registered. The following code should do it. Notice the placement of the `import` statement. It needs to be after the assignment of `app`.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

import login    # Register handlers for /login

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```